# Как правильно использовать методы slice() и trim() в одной строке? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Задание:**

*С помощью метода slice() получите часть предложения, записанного в константу text, c 5 по 15 символы включительно. Полученную подстроку обработайте методом .trim() и выведите на экран длину итоговой подстроки. Выполните эти методы подряд в цепочке без создания промежуточных переменных.*

**Мое решение: Что я не правильно делаю? Спасибо.**

```
const text = 'When \t\n you play a \t\n game of thrones you win or you die.';
console.log(text.slice(4, 16).trim());
```

**Ошибка:**

> console.log
> you play
>
> ```
>   at console.<anonymous> (../../local/lib/hexlet-javascript/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:854:25)
> ```
>
> FAIL  **tests**/solution.test.js   ✕ solution output (59 ms)
>
> ● solution output
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: "7"
> Received: "you play"
> ```

**Я понял что судя по ошибке, ответ должен быть "7", а не "you play", но не понимаю как это сделать.**

Comment: ты не знаешь свойства, показывающее длину строки?

Comment: console.log(text.slice(4, 16).trim(text.length)); по разному делаю. Ошибка

Comment: а если подумать побольше, куда именно пихать length,

Comment: Нигде найти не могу как куда в таком случае пихать)) поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: надо вывести длину строки, которая получилась от предыдущих операций......значит где она должна быть? явно не внутри функции trim

Comment: даже в самом задании написано как нужно делать

Comment: честно не понимаю. console.log(text.slice(4, 16).trim.length());

Comment: уже лучше....только надо понимать, что trim - метод, а length - свойство

Comment: недогоняю вообще(

Comment: Отдохни. Поспи. И потом прочитай заново

Comment: Надо не такыть наугад, а прочитать внимательно что есть что и сделать согласно изученной информации

Comment: =))) задачу надо решить потом спать идти))

Comment: Все сделал))) console.log(text.slice(5, 15).trim().length);

Comment: ..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце не хватает добавить третью опцию которая вычислит длинну строки (.length)

text.slice(4, 16).trim().lenght

Answer (score 0):

console.log(text.slice(5, 15).trim().length);

Comment: Роман, а чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа Андрея, который был дан вчера? Что он дает автору вопроса или базе знаний? (это комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений").